# Problemas de Flutter con el width, por que no ocupa el 100%?

Tags: flutter

siempre estoy teniendo un problema con los tamaños en Flutter (esto es porque vengo de CSS y no entiendo bien como maneja sus tamaños)

Tengo un contenedor dentro de otro con un stack en el medio:

```
                    Container(
                        color: Colors.amber,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: 128,
                        child: Stack(
                          children: [
                            Positioned(
                              bottom: 0,
                              child: Container(
                                width: 100,
                                height: 100,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/decoration.png'),
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover
                                  ),
                                  color: Theme.of(Get.context).colorScheme.redNormal,
                                )
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
```

Esto me hace:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo puedo hacer que el container Rojo (el segundo) use el 100% del wigth del primer contenedor (el padre)? también debe mantener su posición.

Siempre tengo estos problemas de width, tambien estoy pensado que el primer contenedor (el naranja) deberá usar el 100% del que lo contiene.

con width: double.infinity en el contenedor rojo me da:

BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.

These invalid constraints were provided to RenderDecoratedBox's layout() function by the following function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:

Gracias!

Comment: Le estás pasando `width: 100` al container rojo, por eso no ocupa todo el ancho. En este caso 100 no es un porcentaje. Probá pasarle `width: double.infinity` como al container padre.

Comment: por supuesto que lo hice y me da error, RenderBox was not laid out: RenderConstrainedBox#ba504 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, el `Stack` tiene una propiedad `fit`, puedes asignarle `StackFit.expand`.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack/fit.html

También puedes definir el tamaño en el `Positioned.`.

En lugar de :

```dart
                            Positioned(
                              bottom: 0,
                              child: Container(
                                width: 100,
                                height: 100,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/decoration.png'),
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover
                                  ),
                                  color: Theme.of(Get.context).colorScheme.redNormal,
                                )
                              ),
                            )
```

Usa:

```
                           Positioned(
                              bottom: 0,
                              left: 0,
                              height: 100,
                              child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/decoration.png'),
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover
                                  ),
                                  color: Theme.of(Get.context).colorScheme.redNormal,
                                )
                              ),
                            )
```

Ejemplo:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.amber,
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 128,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                height: 100,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ninguna de estos arreglos ha hecho que el container rojo llegue a ocupar el 100% del width del container amarillo, el (100 esta de ejemplo) no quiero que ocupe 100px si no el 100%, no me funcionó ninguno de estos arreglos, sigue quejandose de error

Comment: Ya actualicé mi respuesta, en el stack no es necesario el 100 de with, agregué un ejemplo, espero te sirva. Te invito a mi canal de youtube para que lleves flutter a otro nivel:  youtube.com/diegoveloper :)

Comment: Gracias Diego! ahora si! entonces dandole el positioned donde debe aclarse! muchas gracias! sigo tus videos a full!!!!